# jQuery Facebook/Tumblr-style infinite scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroller

Here's the code: (modified version of a tutorial thanks to hycus.com)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var properlast=10;
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            $("div#loadmoreajaxloader").show();
            $.ajax({

                url: "pinc-myactivity.php?start=" + properlast,
                success: function(html){

                    if(html && $(".activity:last").attr("id") == properlast){
                        $("div#loadmoreajaxloader").before(html);
                        properlast = properlast+10;
                        $("div#loadmoreajaxloader").hide();
                    }else{

                        $("div#loadmoreajaxloader").html("<center>No more posts to show.</center>");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

It pulls ten activity posts at a time. Works great, except for trouble with it repeating the same ten posts twice.

I put a failsafe in to tell it what the last post should have been (properlast variable), check it against the actual last post - $(".activity:last").attr("id"), and only if it matches then post the html and increase the "properlast" variable by ten.

This helped, but repeating posts still occurs when scrolling really fast- so would adding a time delay fix it? I feel like that would be not as ideal because it shouldn't repeat results at all.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to avoid duplicate elements is to ensure that there is only one ajax request in flight at a time.  This is best done by a simple boolean switch

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var properlast = 10;
  var loading = false;
  if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
    if (loading) {
      return;
    }

    $("div#loadmoreajaxloader").show();
    $.ajax({

      url: "pinc-myactivity.php?start=" + properlast,
      success: function(html){

        if(html && $(".activity:last").attr("id") == properlast){
          $("div#loadmoreajaxloader").before(html);
          properlast = properlast+10;
          $("div#loadmoreajaxloader").hide();
        }else{

          $("div#loadmoreajaxloader").html("<center>No more posts to show.</center>");
        }

        loading = false;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Tried it out. Didn't make any difference. Scrolling slow is fine, scrolling fast repeats the results.

Comment: @batoutofhell are you certain the problem is not the PHP service then?

Comment: Yes. The php only returns 10 results at a time.